# Change attr() of an element exist in differnt div having same index

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change `href` of an element from another div's element where both have same index or nth-child number, like:

I want to replace `.nav-tabs a` href to `.tab-content .tab-pane`s `id` where both index number are same,

But my code only works for first anchor, and `i` always return 0:

```
 var i = 0;
 jQuery('#pane').each(function () {
     var p = jQuery(this).attr('id', 'pane-' + randomNumber());
     alert(i);
     jQuery(this).closest('.tab-content').prev().children('ul.nav-tabs li')
         .eq(i).find('a').attr('href', '#' + p.attr('id'));
     i++;
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabbable" id="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="pane">

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="pane">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique on context page! `jQuery('#pane')` will always return only one element. Use class instead or do like lazy people do, use the uggly workaround: `jQuery('[id=pane]')`. BTW, use instead of variable 'i', the each loop index: `jQuery('.pane').each(function(i){...})`

Comment: Same id should not be assigned to multiple elements. Use same class instead.

Comment: means `#pane` must be unique ??

Comment: Yes, or use a class instead.

Comment: @user007 yes `id`'s are unique in an html page

Comment: The ids should be unique. Use a class instead!

Comment: OK, I will use `.tab-pane` instead of `#pane`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function()
{
    var tab_lis = $('.nav-tabs li');
    var serial = 0;

    $('.tab-content>div').each(function ()
    {
      var div = $(this);
      var id = 'd' + (++serial);
      div.attr('id', id);

      var li = tab_lis.eq(div.index());
      var a = li.find('a');

      a.attr('href', '#' + id);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RNmYV/1/

Comment: Do you still seek for an answer to this question?